# ios - can't get the UITableView cell height to be proportional to the amount of text

Tags: ios, ios5, uitableview

I am trying to get the UITableView cells to fit the text.  So far I have something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UILabel *label = nil;

    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyleDefault)
            reuseIdentifier:@"business"];

    NSString *comment = [[items_array objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] objectForKey:(@"comment")];

cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;

        CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(320 - (10 * 2), 20000.0f);

        CGSize size = [comment sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];


        label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

        [label setText:comment];
        [label setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 320 - (10 * 2), MAX(size.height, 44.0f))];

        cell.textLabel.text = comment;  
    }
```

I also have this function

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{    
    NSString *comment = [[items_array objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] objectForKey:(@"comment")];

    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(320 - (10 * 2), 20000.0f);

    CGSize size = [comment sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    CGFloat height = MAX(size.height, 44.0f);

    return height + (10 * 2);
}
```

But it isn't allocating the right amount of height to the cells of the UITableViews. I think I am making some mistakes with how/where I assign the label and the text of the cells.

Please help me understand how it should be.

Thanks!

Comment: I see you making a UILabel in your cellForRowAtIndexPath, but then just setting cell.textLabel to your text.  i.e. you're not adding this UILabel to any existing views.  Have you tried doing setFrame on cell.contentView?

Comment: @CSmith no I have not tried that. You are right in that is where I have my confusion..precisely in which to use textLabel or UILabel ....and how to set it right.

Comment: I posted an answer, this hopefully gets you closer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does this get you closer?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{ 
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"business"]; 

 if (cell == nil)
 {  
  cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyleDefault)reuseIdentifier:@"business"]; 
 }

 NSString *comment = [[items_array objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] objectForKey:(@"comment")]; 

 CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(320 - (10 * 2), 20000.0f); 

 CGSize size = [comment sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap]; 

 UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, MAX(size.height, 44.0f) + 20.0f)]; 
 label.numberOfLines = 0; 
 label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap; 
 label.text = comment;  

 [cell.contentView addSubview:label]; 

}
```

Comment: @cssmith It worked somehow...had to tweek it a bit more.  Your code works very nicely.

Comment: @cssmith I just tested with a longer string and some of it didnt fit. Could it be a problem with the max height? Is there a way to not have a limit on the max height?

Comment: @cssmith the latest got the font to change size so more text fit into it, but there is still some text that got cut off because the cell didn't expand further vertically.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set height of a cell using `-tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath`.

---

**With the new code posted**

Here is how I did it (I used a prototype cell so things may be different for you).

I set the the autosizing of the cell to auto size the height of the label (this may already be set for the textLabel).

Then in `-tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath` I did the following:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{    
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(WIDTH_OF_PROTOTYPE_LABEL, CGFLOAT_MAX);
    size = [TEXT_AT_INDEX_PATH sizeWithFont:FONT_OF_PROTOTYPE_LABEL constrainedToSize:size lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    CGFloat height = size.height + (HEIGHT_OF_PROTOTYPE_CELL - HEIGHT_OF_PROTOTYPE_LABEL);
    return MAX(height, HEIGHT_OF_PROTOTYPE_CELL);
}
```

---

**Update 2**

In looking at your code again, I see two possible problems. 1) You have the width of the textLabel wrong. 2) You should compute the do MAX as the last thing after you compute the final new height.

Comment: I just updated my question. I do have this function, but not sure how/where to make them work together. Plus most of that function's code is in my original function.

Comment: thank you for your help. The other answer worked, but your also got me to advance in my understanding of what is happening - much appreciated.